# Should I use Javascript or PHP to set a global variable to uniquely identify each page in a web app

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, variables, global-variables

I'm hoping to accomplish two things:

1-  Add a unique HTML class to the body tag of each page.

IE...
About page = `<body class="about-page">`
Signup page = `<body class="signup-page">`

`.signup-page { color:red }`

2-  Create a variable that I can use globally in both PHP and Javascript functions throughout my app.

IE...

```
<?php 

if ($uniquePageVariable == 'signup') 
$tmp = 'You are on the signup page';

echo $tmp;


?>
```

---

-What are my options for doing this manually?

IE... going into the include file for each view and manually assigning variable

-What are my options for doing this in an automated fashion?

IE... using the url to create the variable(s)

Comment: `<body class="about-page">` is an HTML class. There is no such thing as a CSS class. People have incorrectly called properties, rules, rulesets, class selectors and all selectors "CSS classes" so it is not a useful term to use.

Comment: corrected.  sry, i haven't been to sleep yet.

Answer (score 4):

To uniquely identify each page in a web app you have to use most natural thing - this page's URL.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/signup/') ...
```

Comment: What would be the most effective way to organize the array/loop if I had to set a unique page title for 20-40 pages?  Also, where does the above need to be placed in order for use in any file?  I've been tinkering around and the spot where the variables are declared seems to effect the results.

Comment: the best way to place this code is `front controller`. and unique page titles are best served from the database.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: With you on the URI, but IMHO this is a very good example of when front controllers make life more complicated - not less.

Answer (score 1):

Automate it by testing the URL and acting accordingly.

This can be done both using javascript and PHP.

Use whatever is easiest for you.